# Gmail alias does not receive email

Tags: email, gmail

I have read (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12096?hl=en) that any Gmail account can receive emails for its plus alias.

So for account@gmail.com when I send email to alias+account@gmail.com
I receive following reply:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     alias+account@gmail.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain nabastu.cz by aspmx.l.google.com. [2607:f8b0:4001:c0e::1b].

The error that the other server returned was:
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 u32si667450ioi.23 - gsmtp


----- Original message -----

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to:content-type;
        bh=rV2o3HVMVpR5MzzOppyyRucNhMlqT6oztVlsvvbztMY=;
        b=g3Wl9gFGh0YR5IHnkD8E9o4PITh9PRE5TUyHPKt7/spToDsItGQKuKKLKn6iUgkyDG
         rqEmGC/jGVIP2z2T1cbSjAvJS5nl2Ti5khtUhZs2C8LddJEtGrRxZDCuFYdObBK9dUWU
         1o0oYHQNEhC4WROuUWp25NFNKv45Tz4XMgWl90T1ZBsWHRczZIAk0EGbwxz6kG20PhEv
         1r/a7/dnYshjVJOfDUvwg5gSF8zd2mZ8/DspuqALbkeRJCVpMGSL+jp1XmH18U8cPFRd
         bVJ4y7HDTOqsVfF1urWbk8OMDNhycR/94ZvickFQ39MMRgX4tNNZj7reQdbWOSzR38uV
         0YLw==
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.107.135.30 with SMTP id j30mr46117827iod.148.1448720587099;
 Sat, 28 Nov 2015 06:23:07 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.79.67.134 with HTTP; Sat, 28 Nov 2015 06:23:07 -0800 (PST)
Date: Sat, 28 Nov 2015 15:23:07 +0100
Message-ID: <CABdkat6ymw=nv3WbPZOgnpdq2vC+FhF0Q7VXqLJ2GzcUdX43CQ@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Alias
From: bankify bankify <my.account@gmail.com>
To: alias+account@gmail.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a113ec64af9129a05259a8b25

test
```

Do I need to enable something? Or this functionality is no longer available?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put it the other way around, so instead of `alias+account@gmail.com`, use `account+alias@gmail.com`.